# Secure SFTP Configuration that Allows SFTP User Write Access

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-12.04

I'm attempting to setup OpenSSH on Ubuntu 12.04 to allow the following

- User can only SFTP (no shell access)
- User can write (upload) files
- Access is secure such that no user can view another user's files and cannot compromise the server

To that end I attempted to setup Chroot following

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring

http://www.serverubuntu.it/SFTP-chroot

Unfortunately I seem to have hit a brick wall summarized by the following:

> It's ChrootDirectory ownership problem, sshd will reject sftp connections to accounts that are set to chroot into any directory that has ownership/permissions that sshd doesn't consider secure. sshd's apparently strict ownership/permissions requirements dictate that every directory in the chroot path must be owned by root and only writable for the owner. So, for example, if the chroot environment is in a user's home directory both /home and /home/username must be owned by root and have permissions along the lines of 755 or 750 ( group ownership should allow user to access ).

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP-chroot

"must be owned by root and only writable for the owner" seems to translate to "only writable by *root*"

That would seem to limit the utility of *chroot* to users that only need to download files.

I attempted to

- Change the home directory group ownership to *sftpusers* (a group I created, of which the user is a member)
- Change file permissions from 755 to 775 to allow the group to write

When I did that, I could no longer log in with SFTP.

Changing the ownership and permissions back restored the ability to log in.

**Question**

*How do I setup SFTP in a secure manner, such that users can upload files to their own home directory?*

Comment: That's the reason I desiced to use FTPS (FTP+SSL) instead.

Comment: @c2h5oh: Just found a solution... posted it.

Answer (score 1):

No sooner had I posed this, I found a solution.

Create a directory *under* the chroot directory, e.g. something like

/home/myuser/transfer

That directory can be writable by the user.